# How to set identical gap between elements when one image is longer than rest

Tags: html, css

I will put here some code for better understanding my need.

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.img{
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.img1{
  width:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='img img1'>
    
  </div>
  <p>
    Xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  </p>
</div>
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='img'>
    
  </div>
  <p>
    yyyyyyyyy
  </p>
</div>
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='img'>
    
  </div>
  <p>
    zzzzzz
  </p>
</div>
```

So as u can see, we have 3 div & p elements. I want to separate this elements with identical gap between them. I want separate red div from text. As u notice, first element is longer than rest. I wouldn't like to use static margin or padding value. Exist better solution?

[image]

Comment: justify: space-around was that tried?

Comment: How would you want it to look like?

Comment: don't look on border xD

Answer (score 0):

You need a container that defines the width of all children. Then, you can set `justify-content: space-between` on `.wrap`, so the text and the red rectangle will get away from each other.
Then, add a `gap` property to `.wrap`, so you'll have a basic gap between the elements to start with.

Here's your snippet with the new adjustments:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: fit-content;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.img1 {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='wrap'>
    <div class='img img1'>

    </div>
    <p>
      Xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='wrap'>
    <div class='img'>

    </div>
    <p>
      yyyyyyyyy
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='wrap'>
    <div class='img'>

    </div>
    <p>
      zzzzzz
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect, but i need <p> in the same line (to the left)